# REST API request for sObject fields and picklist values

Tags: rest-api

I'm able to achieve a rest api request using this url.

na35.visual.force.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/custom_object__c/describe

the problem I have is it returns a ton of data. I just need a few fields from the sObject and the picklist values of those fields. The meta data. I'm creating a form to create new records.

How is it done?

Comment: Will querying data work for you? if so try /services/data/v38.0/query?q=select "fieldstoquery" from object__c where "Your_Criteria" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm

Comment: @Rao I don't think so. I believe the query url is for the records themselves. I need the meta data for the picklists

Comment: You can also query CustomField for custom fields, but there's a limitation that you can only query one field at a time, which is likely to be far less efficient, and only custom fields, not standard fields. That's part of the Tooling API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only describe the entire object, including all fields. Fortunately, you can cache the data and use the If-Modified-Since header to avoid wasting bandwidth between each call. See [Get Object Metadata Changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/sobject_describe_with_ifmodified_header.htm).

## Example SObject Describe request

> /services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Merchandise__c/describe

## Example If-Modified-Since header used with request

> ```
> If-Modified-Since: Wed, 3 Jul 2013 19:43:31 GMT
> ```

## Example response body

> No response body returned

## Example response status code

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
> Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 05:03:24 GMT
> ```